# Caliburn Micro MVVM : How to subscribe and unsubscribe event in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I created a WPF sample (using caliburn micro with MVVM pattern, no code-behind) with a view model and their related views:

- ShellView.xaml and ShellViewModel.cs

The ShellView contains:

- A ComobBox, which contains a list of string, if this combox selection is changed, it will raise comboBox1_SelectionChanged() in ShellViewModel.
- A Button, if click this button, it will raise Button1_Click() to delete the first item of list in ShellViewModel.

My questions:

- If I want to click the button without trigger comboBox1_SelectionChanged in view model, how to do that?
  If it implemented in code-behind, I can do like this:

```
        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectionChanged -= comboBox1_SelectionChanged;
            MyCollection.RemoveAt(0);
            comboBox1.SelectionChanged += comboBox1_SelectionChanged;
        }
```

I have no idea how to achieve this in view model. The following is the code:

ShellView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Views"
             xmlns:cal="http://caliburnmicro.com" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=" auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=" auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectMyListValue}" 
                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action comboBox1_SelectionChanged($source,$eventArgs)]" />
        <Button Name="Button1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Delete" 
                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action Button1_Click($source,$eventArgs)]" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private BindableCollection<string> _myCollection = new BindableCollection<string>() { "item1", "item2"};
        public BindableCollection<string> MyCollection
        {
            get => _myCollection;
            set
            {
                _myCollection = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyCollection);
            }
        }

        private string _selectMyListValue = "item1";
        public string SelectMyListValue
        {
            get => _selectMyListValue;
            set
            {
                _selectMyListValue = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(SelectMyListValue));
            }
        }


        public void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something...
        }

        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyCollection.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution which achieved the goal, but I'm not sure if it's the right way.

There is a "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors" which provided "Interaction.Triggers" that contains "ComparisonCondition". I can use it to bind a value to determine the EventCommand is raised or not.

I updated the code as following:

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using WpfApp.Commands;

namespace WpfApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private bool _IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand = true;
        public bool IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand
        {
            get => _IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand;
            set
            {
                _IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand);
            }
        }

        private BindableCollection<string> _myCollection = new BindableCollection<string>() { "item1", "item2"};
        public BindableCollection<string> MyCollection
        {
            get => _myCollection;
            set
            {
                _myCollection = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyCollection);
            }
        }

        private string _selectMyListValue = "item1";

        public DelegateCommand<object> DoSelectionChangedCommand { get; }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            DoSelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(comboBox1_SelectionChanged, CanExecute);
        }

        private bool CanExecute(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object param)
        {
            SelectionChangedEventArgs e = param as SelectionChangedEventArgs;
            ComboBox item = e.Source as ComboBox; 

            // Do something...

        }

        public string SelectMyListValue
        {
            get => _selectMyListValue;
            set
            {
                _selectMyListValue = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(SelectMyListValue));
            }
        }

        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand = false;
            MyCollection.RemoveAt(0);
            IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**ShellView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="http://caliburnmicro.com" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" 
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Commands"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=" auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=" auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectMyListValue}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventCommand Command="{Binding DoSelectionChangedCommand}" />
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <i:ConditionBehavior>
                            <i:ConditionalExpression>
                                <i:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand= "{Binding IsEnableSelectionChangedCommand}" Operator="Equal"  RightOperand="True"/>
                            </i:ConditionalExpression>
                        </i:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Name="Button1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Delete" 
                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action Button1_Click($source,$eventArgs)]" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can't be fully met, as when you remove the selected item from the collection a change of `SelectedValue` (to `null`) is inevitable.

Furthermore: You don't need to bind to the `SelectionChanged` event. You already have a binding to `SelectedValue`, so the setter of the bound property is called when the selection changes. This doesn't happen, when you remove a value from the collection that is not currently selected.

I would also recommend not to subscribe to the `Clicked` event of the button, but to bind an `ICommand` (added to your viewmodel) to the `Command` property of the button. An easy to use implementation would be the `RelayCommand` from the Windows Community Toolkit. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand. It also isn't difficult to implemnt a version on your own, if you don't want to use the whole toolkit.

Code sample:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object?> execute;

    private readonly Func<object?, bool> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(
        Action<object?> execute,
        Func<object?, bool>? canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute ?? (_ => true);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => this.canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;
}

// on your viewmodel add...
public ICommand RemoveFirstItemCommand { get; set; }

private void RemoveFirstItem(object? param)
{
    if (this.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        this.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

// ...and in the constructor init the command
this.RemoveFirstItemCommand = new RelayCommand(this.RemoveFirstItem);
```